# Best solution for floating imprecision

Tags: ruby, floating-point, precision

I am facing floating imprecision:

```
3.84 + 2.53 #=> 6.369999999999999
```

I can think of the following solution to the problem above, given that the numbers can be `nil`.

```
(num1.to_f + num2.to_f).round(2)
```

where using `to_f` handles `nil`. Or,

```
num1.to_d + num2.to_d
```

or

```
BigDecimal.new(num1.to_s) + BigDecimal.new(nums2.to_s)
```

where using `to_s` handles `nil`.

Which is the best solution to the floating imprecision problem amongst above all? Is there any better solution?

Comment: If you are fine with `float`, you don’t need big decimals.

Comment: Use ternary operator to avoid operation if operands are nil & provide whatever you want in else part

Comment: There is not a "best" solution, it depends on what these numbers are for. Is this a currency calculation, for instance? If so, do you ever need to deal with more than 2 decimal places (for calculating tax etc)? Please give more details.

Comment: Where do the values `3.84` and `2.53` come from? Are these floats already or is that some kind of user input, i.e. strings? Likewise, what kind of output do you need – a float or a string? (or something else)

Comment: What is your "above problem"?

Comment: You have provided 3 different operation with different output possibilities so I am not even clear what you expect. Handling `nil` is ok but what you expect ? float or int ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rational numbers are as precise as integers, as long as you stay in rational land:

```
3.84r + 2.53r
# => (637/100)
```

Obviously, irrational operations will kick you out of there:

```
Math.sqrt(4r)
# => 2.0
```

EDIT: If you are already starting from floats... not as pretty though:

```
3.84.to_r
# => (1080863910568919/281474976710656)
```

so going through the string representation might be better (EDIT: or better yet, use the nice `#rationalize` method):

```
3.84.to_s.to_r
# => (96/25)

3.84.rationalize
# => (96/25)
```

Comment: I wasn't aware that creating a rational number from a decimal literal avoids floating point conversion.

Comment: @Stefan It's not a decimal literal, it's a rational literal :D but it does handle decimal point with arbitrary precision.

Comment: Indeed, I always thought of `r` as a suffix to number literals (because the [`Rational`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/Rational.html) docs say so), assuming `<num>r` to be syntactical sugar for `<num>.to_r`.

Comment: Instead of converting to string, there's also `3.84.rationalize`

Comment: @Stefan: Derp, I just remembered it at the same time :D Yeah. However, `<Num>r`  is actually equivalent to `'<Num>'.to_r`; `#rationalize` can misfire (e.g. `0.123456789123456789.rationalize != 0.123456789123456789r`).

Comment: Or even simpler, `1.0000000000000002.rationalize != 1.0000000000000002r` (`1 + Float::EPSILON`).